# How to build a Telegram bot to suggest you pizza using java?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I created a Main java file and I added an instruction for the bot: say "I love Pizza" on a public channel I created.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  //create a new Telegram bot object to start talking with Telegram
  TelegramBot bot = TelegramBotAdapter.build(“HERE YOUR API KEY”);
  bot.sendMessage(“@pizzaciaopizza”, “I love Pizza”);
  }
}
```

This worked. Good start. Thankfully my bot loves pizza.
I wanted to enable my bot to answer a command like "/recommendPizza" and to answer something.So how can one do this?

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api, right?

I have previously used https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots. It provides a simple listener API to receive updates:

```
public class PizzaBot {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PizzaBot.class.getName());

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TelegramLongPollingBot() {

            @Override
            public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
                Message message = update.getMessage();
                Long chatId = message.getChatId();
                String input = message.getText();
                if ("/recommendPizza".equals(input)) {
                    SendMessage request = new SendMessage();
                    request.setChatId(chatId.toString());
                    request.setText("Have a calzone!");
                    try {
                        sendMessage(request);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not send message", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String getBotUsername() {
                return "YOUR_BOT_USERNAME";
            }

            @Override
            public String getBotToken() {
                return "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try this :)

Comment: Btw, my library also supports listeners now :)